# How setState updates the DOM behind the scenes?

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and how setState works behind the scenes. I read all about the asynchrony of setState. The question I want to ask is when React re-renders the component with new state and updates the DOM. Who exactly updates the DOM? ReactDom or React itself? If it is React DOM, does setState have kinda React DOM api that is called by setState after reconciliation.

Comment: You can look through their source code and see where DOM mutations happen. Why is the answer to this question important, is it just curiosity or does it it matter in your implementation?

Comment: @XCS, curiosity))